# mod_rewrite not working on app_dev in symfony

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, symfony

I want to access http://localhost/myproject/web/app_dev.php in symfony from my http://localhost/myproject. I have it up and running for app.php:

```
# Works if I call http://localhost/myproject
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   Options FollowSymLinks

   RewriteBase /myproject/
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ web/app.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

The same fails with app_dev.php. I thought, that the routing.yml get loaded anyway, since I do not have an routing_dev.yml, it should work out of the box - as I thought. But it does not:

```
# Works not if I call http://localhost/myproject
# Error Message: No route found for "GET /myproject/"

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options FollowSymLinks

    RewriteBase /myproject/
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ web/app_dev.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Why's that?

EDIT:

http://localhost/myproject/web/app_dev.php does work!

EDIT II:
When using the not working .htaccess the images from symfonys error page are fail to load, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are on localhost then you should create a virtual host say `localhost.myproject` and set `web` directory as `DocumentRoot`. If you are in shared hosting then check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10253510/symfony2-on-shared-hosting/10253711#10253711) to get working asset links.

Comment: I don't know why I haven't thought of that.