# Symfony2: How to run the application at root directory without configure virtual host

Tags: symfony, directory, root

I'm using iPage as hosting, which I can't edit the virtual host , the application is now running at

```
http://www.xxxx.com/Symfony/web/app_dev.php
```

Is it possible to make some trick which allow me to run in this URL:

```
http://www.xxxx.com/app_dev.php
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Symfony 2: How to remove the "/web/" folder from the url in a shared hosting?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11929435/symfony-2-how-to-remove-the-web-folder-from-the-url-in-a-shared-hosting)

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Take a look here:

[Symfony 2: How to remove the "/web/" folder from the url in a shared hosting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11929435/symfony-2-how-to-remove-the-web-folder-from-the-url-in-a-shared-hosting/11936099#11936099)

So, you need copy all yours "web" content into public_html (the web root directory) and put th rest: every dir (like src, vendor and so on) at the same level (just like in example I've gave you)